# creating an encrypted (chat room) on python

Tags: python-2.7

i have a faculty task" creating an encrypted chat room on python. I have only basic knowledge of this programming language. can somebody help me to find the client/server CODE. 
thank you,

Comment: Don't bet your whole point at time...

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend the use of this library 
http://twistedmatrix.com/

There is an example of using a chat http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/

And here is how using SSL in twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html

I hope this is useful for you.